# Is it okay to upload non-code files to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I'm going to upload a -mainly PHP- project of mine to [GitHub](https://github.com/), but I'm unsure about uploading all the 'non-code' files like CSS, .htaccess, HTML, images that I use for the website design, etc. and even code files that aren't in PHP (e.g. JavaScript).

Should I upload everything or *only* upload the PHP files if I specified that my repo would contain a PHP project?

Comment: You can upload anything you want (within the size limits). I'm not certain where you "specified that my repo would contain a PHP project", but that's not really relevant to anything.

Comment: Yes, I thought that when GitHub asked for the main language of your repository it was a restriction more than for categorization purposes (like @hd1 said)

Comment: While developing a website, I won't say CSS, HTML & .htaccess are not code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upload everything.

I don't know where you got the idea that revision control is only for code.

Upload *everything.*  Except passwords.

**Clarification:** For each language and toolset, you'll develop a list of files that don't belong in the repository.  For example, you want to keep `*.o` files out of your C project, and `.*.swp` files out of any project (they're vim scratch files).  But it is always easier to delete a file you accidentally added than it is to add a file you forgot to add.  (Deleting a file with sensitive information such as passwords is a different matter, since you need to scrub the file from history as well.)

Comment: Or except *sensitive information* in general. Unless it's a private repo, in which case have fun (still no on the passwords thing though, don't trust Github *that* much).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: how about content that could be problematich with licensing? For example: I found that icon that I want to use in my private application. If I upload it to Github: will I run into copyright problems? This might be a theoretic problem if you develop private, but once it's on Github (and you have a free account), it's being made public...

Comment: @eckes: If you violate copyright law, it is a problem whether or not you use GitHub.

Answer (score 7):

You should upload everything what is needed by your application.

I would just say not to upload generated files or temporally files. E.g. if you had a c++ project you should not upload the final binaries except they are for some kind of final version for an explicit download.

So if you generate while the setup a config file don't load it up. Everything else should be fine.

Comment: I accidentally added build files once. I wasn't happy when I ran out of space and had to rewrite git history with those omitted.

Comment: I don't know github enough, but it should be possible to remove them from the repository and Set them on a kind of block/ignor list.

Comment: Well, `git remove` will keep the files in the revision history. To completely get rid of them, you have to do history rewriting, which will wreak havoc on anyone who has a copy of your repo.

Answer (score 3):

The specification of language seems to be for their categorisation purposes. Most projects that go beyond textbook exercises involve more than 1 language. Upload everything, modulo passwords, as Dietrich  states.

Answer (score 3):

Upload anything you want to Github.  It doesn't even have to be related to programming.  If you've never used Github for anything before, read their help section

http://help.github.com

there is also a good question on SO related to best-practices which I think gives a good overview of how to use git repos in general

[Workflow best practice with git and github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604613/workflow-best-practice-with-git-and-github)

Whatever you do upload just know that unless you pay for a private repo everything you upload will be publicly visible so don't upload anything you wouldn't want others to see or have.  Also, if you have files that are part of your project which shouldn't be uploaded, such as IDE or configuration specific files and the like, you can always add file exclusions to .gitignore.  information on what .gitignore is and how to use it can be found on the git man page here:

http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html

or

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

and once you get good with .gitignore here are some great templates for various project formats

https://github.com/github/gitignore